# UIToolbar Transition Without Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a `UIToolbar` on the bottom. Several of my views have the same exact items on the bottom toolbar, but when it transitions from one view to another it animates, fading the button out and then back in. How can I stop this animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the exact same toolbarItems when you push the next viewController as follows:

```
NextViewController *nextVC = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
nextVC.toolbarItems = self.toolbarItems;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animtated:YES];
```